# Spock unit testing and Inner closures

Tags: groovy, closures, spock

I ran into a rather odd closure issue related to spock unit testing and wondered if anyone could explain this.

If we imagine a dao, model, and service as follows:

```
interface CustomDao {
List<Integer> getIds();
Model getModelById(int id);
}

class CustomModel {
int id;
}

class CustomService {
CustomDao customDao

public List<Object> createOutputSet() {
    List<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>();
    List<Integer> ids = customDao.getIds();
    for (Integer id in ids) {
        models.add(customDao.getModelById(id));
    }
    return models;
}
}
```

I would like to unit test the CustomService.createOutputSet.  I have created the following specification:

```
class TestSpec extends Specification {

def 'crazy closures'() {
    def mockDao = Mock(CustomDao)
    def idSet = [9,10]

    given: 'An initialized object'
        def customService = new CustomService
        customService.customDao = mockDao

    when: 'createOutput is called'
        def outputSet = customService.createOutputSet()

    then: 'the following methods should be called'
        1*mockDao.getIds() >> {
            return idSet
        }

        for (int i=0; i<idSet.size(); i++) {
            int id = idSet.get(i)
            1*mockDao.getModelById(idSet.get(i)) >> {
                def tmp = new Model()
                int tmpId = id // idSet.get(i)
                return tmp
            }
        }

    and: 'each compute package is accurate'
        2 == outputSet.size()
        9 == outputSet.get(0).getId()
        10 == outputSet.get(1).getId()

}
}
```

Notice that in here I test two things. First, I initialize the dao with my mock, verify that the daos are correctly called and return the proper data, and then I verify that I get the proper output (i.e. "`and:`").

The tricky part is the for loop, in which I wanted to return models from the mock dao that are related to the method parameter.  In the above example, if I use a simple `for (__ in idSet)`, the models only return with id 10:  `outputSet.get(0).getId() == outputSet.get(1).getId() == 10`.  If I use the traditional for loop, and set the model with `idSet.get(i)`, I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` .  The only way to make this work is by retrieving the value in a local variable (`id`) and setting with variable, as above.

I know this is related to groovy closures and I suspect that spock captures the mock calls into a set of closures before executing them, which means that the model creation depends on the outer state of the closure. I understand why I would get the IndexOutOfBoundsException, but I don't understand why `int id = idSet.get(i)` is captured by the closure whereas `i` is not.

What is the difference?

Note: this is not the live code but rather simplified to demonstrate the crux of my challenge. I would not and do not make two subsequent dao calls on getIds() and getModelById().

Comment: Why not use >>> to control the values returned by getModelById mock? Seems like a cleaner way to do what you're trying to do. https://spock-framework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html?highlight=sequence%20of%20values

Comment: Unless I am missing something, that is essentially what I am doing. Notice that for getModelById, I use the right shift operator to return a value that is dependent on its input.  In this way I am testing the interaction with the dao.  For each id the method is given, I expect that it will subsequently call with that parameter and return an object related to it.

In my system code, I test further interactions that make it important that I have clearly distinguishable state when evaluating the package list that is returned by the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While stubbing `getModelById` by a closure, the arguments to the closure has to match with that of the method. If you try something like below, you would not need the local variable `id` inside `for` anymore.

```
for (int i=0; i<idSet.size(); i++) {
            //int id = idSet.get(i)
            mockDao.getModelById(idSet.get(i)) >> {int id ->
                def tmp = new Model()
                tmp.id = id // id is closure param which represents idSet.get(i)
                return tmp
            }
        }
```

Simplified version would be to use `each`

```
idSet.each {
    mockDao.getModelById(it) >> {int id ->
        def tmp = new Model()
        tmp.id = id // id is closure param which represents idSet.get(i)
        tmp
    }
}
```

Do we need to worry about how many times method is called if it is being stubbed?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response.  This make sense as a means of explicitly passing arguments into the closure.  What I don't understand is why in my above example id = idSet.get(i) get closure'd while idSet.get(i) does not.  What is the difference?

Comment: @chris.wood Will the closure be able to know what is `i` from `idSet.get(i)` in its local scope?

Comment: That's what is interesting. With spock, it sees i as 2, its value after exiting the for loop.  That must mean that Spock doesn't evaluate the closures until sometime after they are stored. BTW, neither does the example you provided work (I tested earlier) because the evaluation happens inside the closure. I was hoping to understand why `int id = idSet.get(i)` works while i does not.

Comment: @chris.wood I was able to pass the above tests using the same examples I had provided in my answer. I was also able to replicate `IndexOutOfBoundsException` while directly using `idSet.get(i)` inside the closure. I used Grails 2.2.2 test with `spock:0.7` plugin instead of running the tests in a Groovy project. Find it [here](http://pastebin.com/1ewUa6ae).

Comment: @chris.wood If you want I can push the sample project in github for you.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing mutable local variables from a closure whose execution is deferred is a common source of errors not specific to Spock.

> I don't understand why int id = idSet.get(i) is captured by the closure whereas i is not.

The former  gives rise to a separate hoisted variable per iteration whose value is constant. The latter gives rise to a single hoisted variable whose value changes over time (and before the result generator executes).

Instead of solving the problem by introducing a temporary variable, a better solution (already given by @dmahapatro) is to declare an `int id ->` closure parameter. If it's deemed good enough to stub the calls without enforcing them, the loop can be omitted altogether. Yet another potential solution is to construct the return values eagerly:

```
idSet.each { id ->
    def model = new Model()
    model.id = id
    1 * mockDao.getModelById(id) >> model
}
```

Comment: This answered my question exactly.  Thanks.  Passing credit to @dmahapatro for providing a working implementation, although your response explained the closure confusion I had.  Thanks!